# Proof of Cauchys root bounds for polynomials using Gershgorins circle theorem

Tags: geometry, polynomials, proof-explanation, roots

This is my first time posting a question here, so if there's anything about the way I'm posting that I can improve upon, please let me know.

I have to give a presentation on root bounds for polynomials that can be derived from Gershgorins circle theorem and I was given the following excerpt: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2313703?seq=1.

In this paper, there are a bunch of proofs for different root bounds using Gershgorins theorem and I am struggling to comprehend some of them.

The basic idea for most of these proofs is to form the companion matrix $C(f)$ for a polynomial $f(x) = a_n x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_0 $, defining a diagonal matrix $P = diag(b_1,\cdots,b_n)$ and then forming the matrix $P^{-1}CP$, whose eigenvalues are the roots of $f$.

My question is regarding the proof of Cauchys theorem, which states that the moduli of the roots of a polynomial $f$ are less or equal to the positive root of $g(x) = |a_n| x^n - |a_{n-1}|x^{n-1} - \cdots - |a_0|$.
First, we set the entries $b_i$ of the diagonal matrix $P$ to be $b_i = \rho^{n-i}$, which gives us
$
 P^{-1}CP = 
 \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & -a_0 / (a_n \rho^{n-1}) \\
  \rho & 0 & \cdots & 0 & -a_1 / (a_n \rho^{n-2}) \\
  \vdots & \rho & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
  \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 & -a_{n-2} / (a_n \rho) \\
  0 & 0 & \cdots & \rho & -a_{n-1} / a_n\\
 \end{pmatrix}
$
Now, according to the paper, we're supposed to apply Gershgorins theorem to the columns of $P^{-1}CP$ and chose a $\rho$ thats equal to the sum of the moduli of the elements in the last column of the matrix. How does this conclude the proof? And how can I chose $\rho$ to be equal to the sum of the moduli of the last column, when $\rho$ is actually a factor in all those terms?

One more thing:
Apparently, if only the moduli of the coefficients of a given polynomial are known, there cant be a smaller bound than this one by Cauchy (correct me if Im wrong), but how would I go about proving this? I dont need a mathematically sound proof here, just a rough direction of why this holds.

Thank you!!

Comment: two things to start: (1) to clean this up I'd suggest you restrict your attention to monic polynomials for now since rescaling a polynomial by non-zero coefficient doesn't change the roots.  (2) how much do you know about Perron-Frobenius Theory and Companion matrices?  For inuition purposes I would interpret the results through (2) then work-backwards to a standalone Gerschgorin Disc proof.... though honestly P-F Theory seems like a much nicer explanation of the Cauchy Bound

Comment: what I am hinting at is, let $f$ be monic and you have your $g$ defined above -- now consider the Companion Matrix for each -- they are the same except $g$'s Companion Matrix has all components being real non-negative -- so apply https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3619228/rhob-leq-rhob-where-rho-is-the-spectral-radius/3619333#3619333